# Nested if statements in python

Tags: python-3.x

I'm having a few issues with my if statements. I guess I'm confused on how they work.

```
play=True
while play:

    S1=float(input('Enter the percentage of annihilation for s1 e.g 0.5 or .5: '))
    S2=float(input('Enter the percentage of annihilation for s2 e.g 0.5 or .5: '))
    S3=float(input('Enter the percentage of annihilation for s3 e.g 0.5 or .5: '))
    S4=float(input('Enter the percentage of annihilation for s4 e.g 0.5 or .5: '))

    AP= S1+S2+S3+S4

    while True:
        if AP == 1.0:
            play = False
            break
        elif AP < 1.0:
            B = input('Annihilation percentage is under 100%\nWould you like to continue? (y/n): ')
            if B in ('y', 'n'):
                if B == 'y':
                    break
                if B == 'n':
                    play = False
                    break
            print('Invalid input')
        elif AP > 1.0:
            A = input('Annihilation percentage over 100%\nWould you like to try again? (y/n): ')
            if A in ('y', 'n'):
                if A == 'y':
                    continue
                if A == 'n':
                    play=False
                    break
            print('Invalid input')
        else:
            print("Goodbye")
            break

    ### the rest of the code###
```

If AP ==1 then I want to continue with the rest of the code, but if AP>1 I want the user to reenter the values again or stop the program, and if AP<1 I want the user to continue if they are pleased or stop the program if they are not pleased.

Every time I run this it will loop back to the begging. Doesn't break stop this from happening, and continue restarts from the beginning?

Comment: Does it work if `AP==1.0` from the start? Does `AP` change between iterations?

Comment: `break` breaks only the inner loop, not the outer loop. Also `print("Goodbye")` is never executed.

Comment: Yes AP==1.0 works from start, and yes AP can change each time the program runs.

Answer (score 0):

You have a nested while loop; breaking only breaks out of the nested while loop, not the container loop. You need to add a break statement after the nested loop:

```
play=True
while play:

    S1=float(input('Enter the percentage of annihilation for s1 e.g 0.5 or .5: '))
    S2=float(input('Enter the percentage of annihilation for s2 e.g 0.5 or .5: '))
    S3=float(input('Enter the percentage of annihilation for s3 e.g 0.5 or .5: '))
    S4=float(input('Enter the percentage of annihilation for s4 e.g 0.5 or .5: '))

    AP= S1+S2+S3+S4

    while True:
        if AP == 1.0:
            play = False
            break
        elif AP < 1.0:
            B = input('Annihilation percentage is under 100%\nWould you like to continue? (y/n): ')
            if B in ('y', 'n'):
                if B == 'y':
                    break
                if B == 'n':
                    play = False
                    break
            print('Invalid input')
        elif AP > 1.0:
            A = input('Annihilation percentage over 100%\nWould you like to try again? (y/n): ')
            if A in ('y', 'n'):
                if A == 'y':
                    continue
                if A == 'n':
                    play=False
                    break
            print('Invalid input')
        else:
            print("Goodbye")
            break
    break  # <-- Add a break statement
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have nested while loops that are always true. Try refactoring without the outer while loop.